# Removing nestled arrays using KnockoutJS

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

First week using KnockoutJS here and looking to find a simple method to remove a child array from its dynamically added parent array. Visit http://jsfiddle.net/hotdiggity/HC9wU/ for a working example of below:

```
function Parent(name, children) {

    var self = this;

    //self.name = ko.observable(name);

    self.children = ko.observableArray(children);

    self.addChild = function () {
        self.children.push(new Child(""));
    }

    self.removeParent = function (parent) {
        vm.removeParent(self);
    };

}

function Child(name) {

    var self = this;

    //self.name = ko.observable(name);

    self.removeChild = function (child) {
        vm.removeChild(self);
        // this.child.remove(child);
    };
}

function ParentChildViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.parents = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addParent = function () {
        self.parents.push(new Parent("", []));
    };

    self.removeParent = function (parent) {
        self.parents.remove(parent);
    }

    // remove child from the children list somehow
    self.removeChild = function (child) {
        self.children.remove(child);
    }

};

var vm = new ParentChildViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: "find a simple method to remove a child array from its dynamically added parent array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store a reference to the `Parent` in the `Child`, and move the `removeChild` function into the parent instead of the VM. Then from within the `Child` you can do something like this:

```
self.removeChild = function () {
    self.parent.removeChild(self);
};
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpallas/LwcRf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/cKzn8/5/

The problem is with `ParentViewModel` it does not have a children.

```
// remove child from the children list somehow
self.removeChild = function (child) {
    self.children.remove(child);
}
```

I added a reference to the parent:

```
self.removeChild = function (child) {
    child.parent.children.remove(child);
    // this.child.remove(child);
};
```